# String обрезает куски текста, возможно, из-за нехватки памяти

Tags: java

Как я понял, *Java* выделяет определенные КБ в оперативной памяти, и после того как я в обычный `String` внесу огромное количество текста, на выходе я получаю обрывки.

Текст приходит из `UrlConnect` (точно не помню как пишется), который достает определенные данные из интернета. Известен размер ответа от сервера (количество символов).

Все функции, которые есть у меня, работают только с `String`. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А где сам код? Одного текстового описания с ошибками вряд ли хватит для решения проблемы.

Comment: Java никогда ничего не обрезает из-за нехватки памяти. Если у Java действительно заканчивается память, она выкидывает `OutOfMemoryError` и прекращает выполнение программы. Ваша проблема в чём-то другом. В чём - сложно сказать, не видя вашего кода.

Comment: Я пробовал использовать StringBuffer и задать в него текст и количество символов и он не обрезал данные но работать с ним я не мог, даже после toString я получал обрывки смотрел содержимое StringBuffer через System.out.print и там обрывков небыло.

Comment: UrlConnector читает сколько может. Это нормально. Если нужен весь текст - читайте все. В документации все есть https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: Спасибо огромное) я даже не знал, ты оказался прав, ответишь отмечу как верный ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim, не могли бы вы оформить комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы закрыть вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось все дело в `URLConnection`

```
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
      System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Взято отсюда [reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)
Отлично работает теперь.